# Remove comma in a field but not delimeter in powershell when not all values are in commas

Tags: powershell, csv

I receive a CSV file, in which some records for some fields have commas in them. So when I open the file in notepad a row looks like the following

> `1,John,Wayne,"movies,actor",1950s`

I have scrambled to write the syntax to remove the comma between movies and actor in column 4 in the example above and replace it with space. And then output the file as CSV again.

Here is what I have below, which replaces the entire string "movies,actor" with space.

```
(Get-Content $path) -replace '(".*),(.*")',' ' | Out-File -Encoding UTF8 $newpath
```

How do I replace only the comma with space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually do it much simpler with -replace. When replacing, you can reference the capture groups directly as below:

```
(Get-Content $path) -replace '"(.*?),(.*?)"','$1 $2'
```

Its very similar to the OP solution, except you create two capture groups with only the words, not the quotes. Then the two values are referenced directly in the replace string as $1 and $2 respectively.

Comment: This works on what OP posted but it's going to break sooner or later. If the files contain something like `1,John,Wayne,"movies,actor","1950s"`. You can adjust by using a non greedy search but I'm pretty confident someone can come up with an input that would break that too. In the end, the most robust solution is what Nick posted.

Comment: I'm pretty confident I can come up with an input that would break Nicks too :) But I take your point. Changing to non-greedy or word matching would solve that fairly easily, assuming that is the only field that can contain multiple values. However, if a solution is needed that accounts for possible quotes and commas in all the other fields as well, then an entirely different solution is needed.

Comment: @MarkJakobsen You have made the assumption here that OP is fine with commas being removed from every column in the csv, Even though OP states column 4 as being the one he wants commas removed from.

Comment: @Nick You are right, given the first line stating "some records for some fields" i took it to mean that the specific problem with column 4 was just an example of an issue, and not the only place it could happen. I could absolutely be wrong, but doing a non-greedy search and replace would work either way.

Comment: @MarkJakobsen - that would require the `Import-Csv` to misbehave and then it's not your problem anymore, it's Microsofts ;). ftr - for one off solutions, I would definitely use something like your answer though.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers Absolutely agree, although I'm pretty sure my boss would call it my problem :D CSV files are always difficult in my experience. Formatting depends so much on the creating and consuming services.

Comment: Thank you @MarkJakobsen,

Answer (score 1):

So you could try and write regex to strip the commas but I would tend to break it out like this for supportability and ease of modifying additional fields.

```
$csv = import-csv C:\Old.csv
$NewCSV = @()

Foreach($row in $csv)
{
    $Object = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
    $Object | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name "ID" -Value $csv.ID
    $Object | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name "First" -Value $csv.First
    $Object | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name "Last" -Value $csv.Last
    $Object | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name "Desc" -Value $csv.Desc -replace ","," "
    $Object | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name "Year" -Value $csv.Year
    $NewCSV += $Object
}

$NewCSV | Export-Csv C:\New.csv
```

- Import the csv
- Create a new object, populate it with the rows from $csv
- As we add each row to NewCSV we do a replace on commas
- Export the NewCSV object

It looks complex but you can almost compact it in to one line using the pipeline

`$csv | % { $_.Desc = $_.Desc -replace ","," "; $_ | Export-Csv C:\New.csv -Append -NoClobber}`

Comment: Loving regex but this to me is the most robust, future proof solution.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers Regex is a powerful tool that can solve or your problems or just lock up your entire app if you don't write it properly. The assumptions being made in these other answers are clear examples of why jumping to regex for every problem causes issues down the line.

Answer (score 0):

we can do this in online with regex, like this:

```
(Get-Content D:\dummycsv.csv) | %{if($_ -match '(".*),(.*")'){$_ -replace $matches[0],($matches[1]+' '+$matches[2]);$_}}
```

I'm matching the regex and utilizing the match groups that you are using with `$matches` variable

Comment: See the bottom of my answer for where i compact my answer in to one line. It is shorter, easier to read and more efficient. You simply don't need to mess around with match variables and if statements. You're over complicating it.

Comment: @Nick missed it, my bad but i believe  your oneliner still requires the creation of $csv object.Let the OP decide which one suits him

Comment: It does require it yes, Its trivial to add. This isnt a code for free service I expect people to read and understand. For instance your one liner doesn't include the exporting csv like mine does.